# Inserting an image into a Google Sheet using Google Scripts?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Does anyone know if it is possible to insert an image from a URL into a Google Sheet using Google Scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1 (recommended):

Use directly the [insertImage(url, column, row)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageurl,-column,-row) which accepts the url of the image:

```
function imgToSheet() {
  const img_url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/368px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //change to the name of your sheet
  // Insert the image in cell B1.
  sh.insertImage(img_url, 2, 1); 
}
```

---

### Solution 2:

You can use [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)) to fetch an image from a `url` and then [insertImage(blobSource, column, row)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#insertimageblobsource,-column,-row) to insert the image to the sheet.

**Code snippet:**

```
function insertImageOnSpreadsheet() {
  const img_url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/368px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//change to the name of your sheet
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(img_url);
  const rd = response.getContent();
  // Insert the image in cell B1.
  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(rd, 'image/png', 'MyImageName');
  sh.insertImage(blob, 2, 1);
}
```

**Limitations:**

Unlike Solution 1, the maximum supported blob size for Solution 2 is 2MB.

---

### Solution 3 - Google Sheets Formula:

You can use [IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en) which can locate the image inside a particular cell.

`=IMAGE("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/368px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png")`